# Data Annotation not working with IE8 and telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, data-annotations, telerik-grid

**The problem**

Using Telerik Grid and only with IE8, When I'm Editing a field of a grid that's customized with Data Annotations with wrong values I'm getting an error 500 because it's going to the server action with wrong parameters.

I was reading that's because some versions of jquery validation have a Bug, but I can't solve it updating plugins and libraries.

**The question**

I'll would like to know which version of each jquery I Should use in order to solve that problem, because maybe I'm not making a good plugin mixture.

**The code**

Plugins:

- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.2
- jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1
- Unobtrusive Ajax support library for jQuery

The View:

```
 @(
Html.Telerik().Grid<ZoneData>()
    .Name("zoneDataModel")
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().Text("Add Zone"))
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(param => param.Id))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 520px;" })
    .NoRecordsTemplate("No existen resultados...")

    .DataBinding(
        dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                           .Select("SelectGrid", Controllers.Zone, Model)
                           .Update("UpdateGrid", Controllers.Zone, Model)
                           .Insert("InsertGrid", Controllers.Zone, Model)
                           .Delete("DeleteGrid", Controllers.Zone, Model)
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(param => param.Code);
            columns.Command(commands =>
                {
                    commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                    commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                }
                ).Width(100);
        })

    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)   
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                  )
```

The Model:

```
public class ZoneData
    {
        public string Id{ get; set; }

        [Range(0, 999,ErrorMessage = " ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
        [StringLength(3,ErrorMessage = " ")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve that error with these configuration:

- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.2
- jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1
- Unobtrusive Ajax support library for jQuery